# Master page not loading in child content in Umbraco CMS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have a dynamic logo which is in master page, it's load in Parent page(Home) but doesn't load in child page.

Please help..!!

Thank-you..!!

Comment: Is it the logo having trouble or the master page? Check the logo and make sure that the image path is relative to the root of the application or domain. It could simply be that the URL has formatted is relative to the page, which can work on the home page but not on any other page that has a directory in the path.

Answer (score 1):

If you have selected this logo on the parent page (Home) - when on a child page you need to either access the parent page and get the logo property from that, or make sure that the code you use to fetch the logo property is set to be recursive. Recursive means that if it cannot find the property on the current page, it will automatically try to get it from the parent page(s).

Depending on how you access the property value, IIRC you usually pass in an extra argument (true) to the `GetPropertyValue` method to make it recursive.